# How frequently can I call facebook debug_token API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-oauth

I am building an application with Facebook login (server-side workflow). I wish to inspect all facebook access tokens for expiration.

What's the ideal design to do this using the facebook debug token API? And how often can I call the debug-token API on facebook servers? Is there a ratelimit for o-auth APIs too?

Comment: hello there! did you manage to clarify this question by any chance?